# Go all goroutines are asleep deadlock

Tags: go

Can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the error message: fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!.

I suspected a race condition was occurring in my   block below which should only execute after the channel is closed.

I thought adding a sync WaitGroup would help, but it's only given me this deadlock.  What I have looks close to the samples I've seen online, so I'm just not sure what's wrong here.

```
func S3UploadFolder(instance *confighelper.Instance, sess *session.Session, 
    srcFolder string, bucketName string) (err error) {

    log.Println("S3UploadFolder", srcFolder, bucketName)

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    // find files recursively
    walker := make(fileWalk)
    wg.Add(1)

    go func() {

        // Gather the files to upload by walking the path recursively
        if err := filepath.Walk(srcFolder, walker.Walk); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln("Walk failed:", err)
        }
        wg.Done()
        close(walker)

    }()
    wg.Wait()

    for path := range walker {
    // THE GO routine above needs to have finished by the time this for loop 
       // ranges over the channel
         fmt.Println(path)

 }



return
}


type fileWalk chan string

func (f fileWalk) Walk(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if !info.IsDir() {
        f <- path
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: The main goroutine does not receive on the channel before calling wg.Wait().  The walker goroutine blocks on send to the channel because there is no receiver.  You are not showing all relevant code, but the fix is probably to remove all code related to the wait group.

Comment: sorry, yes the <SOME_OTHRE_CODE> portion contains a range over the channel.  I will update my question to include this code.       I'm trying to wait until the go routine is finished before continuing to the block <SOME_OTHER_CODE>

Comment: Why does the walker goroutine need to complete before the loop that ranges over the channel?

Comment: I'm addressing a defect where some files are not being included in the for range. I was suspecting a race condition where a go thread is still finding files by the time the for range statement is encountered. My thought is at this point the channel is not completed so ranging will only be a subset of total files found in the walker.  This is why I put the sync wait in place.

Comment: Range on a channel does not complete until the channel is closed.  The walker goroutine does not close the channel until the walk is complete.  The channel operations are not losing file names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `walker` channel is unbuffered.  Communication on an unbuffered channel does not proceed until until a sender and receiver are ready.

The deadlock is this: The main goroutine waits on the walker goroutine to complete by calling wg.Done(). The walker goroutine waits on the main goroutine to receive on the channel.

Fix the program by removing all code related to the wait group. The wait group is not needed. Range over the channel in the main goroutine does not complete until the channel is closed by the walker goroutine. The walker goroutine does not close the channel until the walk is complete. No other coordination is required.

You can also fix the code by removing the goroutines and channels:

```
err := filepath.Walk(srcFolder, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if info.IsDir() {
        return nil
    }

    // Insert body of for path := range walker here ... 
    fmt.Println(path)

    return nil
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Another option is to create a buffered channel with capacity greater than the number of files that will be walked, but this requires knowing the number of files in advance and provides no benefit over collecting the file names in a slice.

Answer (score 1):

As written (and shown), you definitely *must not* call `wg.Wait()` before running your `for path := range walker` loop.  You *may* (but don't need to) call `wg.Wait()` when the loop terminates.  You don't need the `wg` variable at all.

Your comment says:

```
// THE GO routine above needs to have finished by the time this for loop 
// ranges over the channel
```

but there is nothing in the `for` loop that requires the function to be finished, and there is something—the overall strategy here—that requires that the goroutine *not* be *blocked in a send*, as the `for` loop will only finish when the sender—the goroutine—closes the channel.

(See [Cerise Limón's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57403813/1256452) for why the goroutine becomes blocked in the send.)